# How to adjust the size of ctypes messagebox

Tags: python

```
    if(int(row[3])>=5):
        mymessage = 'A message'
        title = 'Popup window'
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "mymessage", "title", 0)
    else:
        continue
```

I opened the csv file and wrote a code to put up a warning window. However, I don't know how to adjust the window size through ctype. I want to make that window bigger. It's also good to recommend other ways.

To confirm this, I checked the Python document and found no results.

Comment: That's a [Windows thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxa), not a ctypes thing.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Oh I got it. So I changed it to Win32 MessageBox. But with the built-in warning window, it still seems impossible to change the font or window size.